# Java Spring - Mybatis - Mysql Transaction not working

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-transactions

We are using the Spring boot/ MySQL/ mybatis combination for our new project.
mybatis-spring for the transaction management.

The MySQL engine we are using is innoDB. We are for the first time using the MySQL DB for a micro service.

The issue we are facing is that the transactions are not rolling back on DB even though the spring Transaction trace logs says they are. 
The log

> TRACE TransactionInterceptor:545 - Completing transaction for [service.EntityActionServiceImplementation.updateApplicationStatus] after exception: business.exception.BusinessException: / by zero
>   2018-11-14 16:22:32 TRACE RuleBasedTransactionAttribute:134 - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on business.exception.BusinessException: / by zero
>   2018-11-14 16:22:32 TRACE RuleBasedTransactionAttribute:151 - Winning rollback rule is: RollbackRuleAttribute with pattern [business.exception.BusinessException]
>   2018-11-14 16:22:32 TRACE TransactionSynchronizationManager:248 - Removed value [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionHolder@6a1568d6] for key [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSessionFactory@3db65c0d] from thread [main]
>   2018-11-14 16:22:32 TRACE TransactionSynchronizationManager:142 - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@73bb573d] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@76cdafa3] bound to thread [main]
>   2018-11-14 16:22:32 TRACE TransactionSynchronizationManager:248 - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@73bb573d] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@76cdafa3] from thread [main]
>   2018-11-14 16:22:32 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:340 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
>   2018-11-14 16:22:32 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:836 - Initiating transaction rollback
>   2018-11-14 16:22:32 DEBUG DataSourceTransactionManager:341 - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [HikariProxyConnection@16957838 wrapping oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@11c78080]
>   2018-11-14 16:22:32 TRACE TransactionSynchronizationManager:336 - Clearing transaction synchronization

CODE Block

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = BusinessException.class)
            public boolean updateApplicationStatus(){
    try{
    }catch(Exception ex){
     throw new BusinessException(ex.getMessage(), ex.getCause());
    }
}
```

The behaviour changes if I set an auto-commit false for the data source. in this scenario, the Transaction is not committing at all.

The BusinessException extends a RunTimeException.

The Schema and table engines are InnoDB.

Are we missing any mysql Specific settings?

Answer (score 0):

I was using multiple transaction managers for the multiple databases. Added the transaction manager identifier in the annotation solved the issue.

Comment: where were you went wrong ? have you done full research before posting question here.

Comment: Yes for 3 days I was sitting behind this issue. The app was using multiple databases and hence multiple transaction managers. One for the Oracle database and one for my SQL. We were using the MySQL for the first time. The issue was that the transaction trace log showed roll back on a runtime exception but it was not happening in real. The database the transaction was committed. This behaviour was happening for the MySQL database.  Later realized the transaction annotation we can specify the transaction managers, which solved whole issue.